# Bodies of constant width?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, constant-width

In two-dimensional case one can generalize *figures of constant width* as figures which can rotate in a convex polygon.
Here is one example which can be used to drill triangular holes:

[image]

I would like to know what happens with this generalization in dimension $3$ and maybe higher.
Obviously a body of constant width $1$ can rotate arbitrary in a unit cube.
More formally, given a body $B$ of constant width $1$
and $A\in SO(3)$ there is $v\in \mathbb R^3$ such that
$$A(B)+v\subset\square,$$
where $\square$ is unit cube.
On the other hand, except for the cube, I do not see any other examples of convex polyhedron which have nontrivial rotating bodies (i.e. distinct from the inscribed ball).

I hope that the answer is known.
(= I hope I should wait for the answer and I do not have to think.)

The question is inspired by this one: "[Local minimum from directional derivatives in the space of convex bodies](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86653/)."

Comment: These bodies are called "rotors" of the corresponding cavity. A full classification of non-trivial (i.e. other than bodies of constant width) rotors is known. A good reference on these is "Geometric Applications of Fourier Series and Spherical Harmonics" by Helmut Groemer. As I recall, only the regular simplex and cross-polytope admit non-trivial rotors in dimensions four and above. In three-dimensions, there are more cases.

Comment: @Yoav, why don't you write it as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting used to how things work here on MO. Thanks for the MOtiquette pointer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found the reference I was looking for. The full list of cases under which $K$ is a rotor in a cavity shaped like the polytope $P$ is available on page 27 of the notes titled "[The use of spherical harmonics in convex geometry](http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/rschnei/Vortr%E4ge.Kent.pdf)" by Rolf Schneider. They are available under "Course Materials" on his [website](http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/rschnei/). As I recall, there is one more non-trivial case in $d=3$ if the cavity is allowed to be unbounded (e.g. a cone), and this case appears in the more complete list in Groemer's book.

Answer (score 19):

This adds nothing to Yoav Kallus' answer, but I was curious to see what these rotors look like
(Schneider's notes has no figures).
I found grainy photos of rotors for the cube, the regular octahedron, and the regular tetrahedron
in a 50-year old paper by
Michael Goldberg,
"Rotors in Polygons and Polyhedra,"
[*Mathematics of Computation*, Vol. 14, No. 71 (July, 1960), pp. 229-239](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2003162):

     
[image: Rotors]

(They remind me of stones found on a beach!)

Of course one can find much better examples of cube rotors, which as Anton points out, are just constant-width bodies.  E.g., this is from the cover of Bryant and Sangwin's 2008 [*How Round Is Your Circle*](http://press.princeton.edu/TOCs/c8624.html) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150417145613/http://press.princeton.edu/TOCs/c8624.html) and [an alternative link](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691149929/how-round-is-your-circle)):

   
[image: Constant width bodies]