# General Isoperimetric Inequality via Representation Theory of SO(n)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, dg.differential-geometry, isoperimetric-problems, fourier-analysis

Is there a known proof of the $n$-dimensional isoperimetric inequality which generalizes Hurwitz's proof using Fourier analysis in the $2$-dimensional case?

Specifically, I imagine such a proof would replace $S^1 \cong \text{SO}(2)$ with the group $\text{SO}(n+1)$, and we would decompose a smooth function on $S^n$ according to the representation theory of $\text{SO}(n+1)$, and then express the volume and surface area in terms of the "Fourier coefficients".

If this doesn't work, why not?

Comment: Sean: Out of curiosity, are you just reading up on isoperimetric inequalities, or planning to use this to prove new ones?

Comment: Reading up, mainly, and learning about Fourier analysis and representation theory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the second time today (see [Bodies of constant width?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86742)), I give the answer: see "Geometric Applications of Fourier Series and Spherical Harmonics" by Helmut Groemer. That book deals exactly with your question, and the answer is yes.